# How to convert jquery function to nodejs module

Tags: node.js, ejs, koa

I build a web page with nodejs & koa & ejs, and in `webpage.ejs`, there's a function like following

```
 <a id="createACode"></a>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
 <script>
  var code;
  function createCode(){
    code = "";
    var codeLength = 6;
    var checkCode = document.getElementById("createACode");
    var random = new Array(2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','J','K','M','N','P','Q','R',
    'S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z');
    for(var i = 0; i < codeLength; i++) {
        var index = Math.floor(Math.random()*30);
        code += random[index];
    }
    createACode.text = code;
  }
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#createACode").click(function(){
        createCode();
    });
  });
</script>
```

When I click the `a` link with ID `createACode`, its text will be changed, and `app.js` like this

```
 .get('/webpage', async ( ctx )=>{
     await ctx.render('webpage', {
     });
 })
```

And if I want to convert this function `createCode` to module in nodejs, and how to convert, and use it? Many thanks.

Comment: hi @yupang Can you please tell us what you want to achieve here. Need a bit clarification to get it solve. Thanks

Comment: @biswajit-rout sorry for that, I mean is there any way to achieve the function in `app.js` instead of in `webpage.ejs`?

Comment: @yupang You could implement `createCode` in **app.js** but if you want to change DOM upon pressing that button, you either need to reload the page (and modify the server code to generate a new code and pass it as a variable to render function) or send an AJAX request to the server and update DOM according to the response.

Comment: @fardjad I see, thank you so much.